# How do I figure out what files are not being used in a website/web app?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a web app and the backend of a website.

I have gone through many prototypes taking out links to files and not deleting and using less.js and coffee to make life easier.

Is there anyway I can programmatically figure out what I can delete without breaking anything?

Comment: So it's programmatically? Like in that you are writing your own software to do this, or as in that you are searching for software to do this and maybe should be moved to softwarerecs.se?

Comment: I am looking for a software that does this. And what is softwarerecs.se?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a messy project with a significant amount of redundant files and don't know what to delete, I'd try the other way around: Start a new project and only copy over the things you need, if you'll miss something, you'll notice it.

I always get a fresh and stable feeling when I use this strategy.

But it might be unsuitable if your system is too big or you have an unfavorable ratio of keep/throw.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a manual process, but I use my IDE's find-all command to search for references in the project. If an object or file isn't referenced anywhere, I deem it delete-able.

Comment: That's what I have been using but it is just so tedious. Is there at least an auto change for linked files being moved? I am just extremely tired of working on this project.

Comment: If you only care about optimization, and use a build system like requirejs, you don't need to delete anything. If it's not used, it won't be included in the compiled files.